# Android Log Array List content

Tags: android, arraylist

I have this kind of List:

```
List<Movie> filteredList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

I am not able to Log all the content of this Arraylist.

I tried:

```
for (Movie result : filteredList)  
{
    Log.e("Agil_Limits - " , result.toString());
}
```

I also tried:

```
Log.d("AAA", Arrays.toString(filteredList.toArray()));
```

But in all cases this is what is logged:

```
com.myapp.Movie@709779f
com.myapp.Movie@57490ec
com.myapp.Movie@951ccb5
```

Is there a way to log the content of this list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your own implementation of `toString` for your `Movie` class, e.g.:

```
class Movie {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return "Movie " + this.id ///... all you want to print
  }
}
```

In this case, this method will be called in any place the string representation of the instance required.